# Can't add .png to document

Tags: includegraphics, png

I am new to LaTeX and currently am struggling with inserting a .png. Also, I am new to this forum so please tell me if anything is missing for the question. I have looked for similar topics, however I have not found anything.

I use texlive as backend and TeXstudio as editor. I am using the graphicx package and want to insert my .png in my document using the following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{Test_circuit.png}
        \caption{test}
        \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

However, in my PDF document, all I see is a box with the name "Test_circuit.png" inside it and the real picture does not show up. I attached the picture below.

[image]

Can anyone help me and tell me where my error is in my LaTeX document?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the draft option somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have just changed it and this solved my issue. Thank you very much, you saved me much time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: fine. And to answer if your question is missing something: you should have shown a small complete example, starting with \documentclass. Then one wouldn't have to guess if you use draft but could see it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will remember this for the future. 
Regarding the closing. Can I do this?